# Xamarin : Android special style radio buttons

Tags: android, xamarin, settings

I would like to implement radio button selection for my application settings the same way it is implemented in android settings part of the android operating system.

The radio buttons I mean is displayed in images below.

**Current selected value for the "Sleep" option is "After 2 Minutes of inactivity"**

[image]

**When User taps on "Sleep", radio buttons list appears as below to make the new selection**

[image]

Any idea what is this kind of view (control)? or is it custom implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I found out this could be achieved using Dialogs, there is a very nice article about doing this on this blog post

http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/02/using-dialogs-in-mono-for-android.html